# Moving from setInterval method to requestAnimationFrame with sprite

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, requestanimationframe

I am trying to use the method 'requestAnimationFrame' with the help I can find on Internet. I can move an element, but when I want to do it with sprites, I am lost.

For example, the code below is working normally with 'setInterval', but I cannot manage to make it work with 'requestAnimationFrame'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Animating Sprites in HTML5 Canvas</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

<style>
.demo {background: #aaaaaa;}
#myCanvas{background: #cccccc}
</style>

</head>

<body class="demo">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="100"></canvas>

<script>

(function() {

// Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// Set the fill style for the drawing context.
ctx.fillStyle = '#3399ff';

    // VARIABLES
    var width = 48;           // Width CANVAS
    var height = 60;          // Height CANVAS
    var xFrame = 0;           // Frame x coordinate
    var yFrame = 0;           // Frame y coordinate
    var dxFrame = 0;          // Frame dx position in canvas
    var dyFrame = 0;          // Frame dy position in canvas
    // SPRITE used
    image = new Image()
    image.src = 'myRunner2.png';
    //
    var requestID;

// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
return  window.requestAnimationFrame || 
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame || 
        function(/* function FrameRequestCallback */ callback, /* DOMElement         Element */ element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

    // FUNCTION DRAWING MOVE (xFrame = 0 & yFrame = 1)      
    var drawMove = function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(image, width * xFrame, height * yFrame, width, height, dxFrame, dyFrame, width, height);
        if (xFrame == 7) {
            xFrame = 0;
        } else {
            xFrame++
            dxFrame+=2;
        }
        //window.requestAnimFrame(eMove);
        }
    // ANIMATION in 3 moves: Idle + Move + Tired
    var intA;
    function eMove() {
        // Runner in motion (8 frames)
        yFrame = 1;
        xFrame = 0;
        clearInterval(intA);
        intA = setInterval(drawMove, 100);
    }
    eMove();
}());

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I am looking for help about this issue, a portion of code will be great but a way to work or a direction to look for will be good as well. How to manipulate sprite with the method 'requestAnimationFrame'?

Ultimately, my goal is to move a sprite in one direction and the background in the other direction. I can move the sprite in one direction with setTimeout/setInterval methods alone or I can move in the other direction the background with 'requestAnimationFrame', but also separately.

I hope you understand my problem.
Thank you,

JLuc01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For requestAnimationFrame to work well it needs an accurate timer by which it can update the progress. The animation would then also depend on this variable. Of course a total duration will have to be set as well (to measure the progress). Here's a general piece of code :

```
var initial = update = new Date().getTime(), progress = 0, duration = 2000;
requestAnimationFrame(frameSequence);

function frameSequence() {

update = new Date().getTime();
var elapsed = update-initial;
progress = Math.max(elapsed/duration, 1);

someFunction(); // do calculations and implement them based on progress

if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(frameSequence);
}
```

And a live example (relevant code at the bottom)

http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/vEzqoX?editors=001

Edit - some comments promoted to update :

The requestAnimationFrame call is just a basic loop really to replace the timeout. It could be as simple as using `requestAnimationFrame(drawMove)` instead of `clearInterval(intA); intA = setInterval(drawMove, 100)`. It'll probably do the whole thing in 8/60 of a second that way though (I see there are 8 frames and 60 is the common display refresh rate) - hence a timer would be needed.

This would optimise and work for sure : `setInterval(requestAnimationFrame(drawMove), 100)`. It will not force a frame on the display then like a timeout does (giving performance issues and flickering) but make it wait for the first appropriate instance when there is a new paint of the screen. But not using timeouts at all is a much better approach.

Comment: I can understand your answer about the use of a timer and the progress update, but to use it properly, it is not that easy. Your code does not talk to me very well. Anyway, thank you for your help, but I think I found an interesting link to solve a part of my problem: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/

Comment: That's about creating sprites mostly... the part about requestAnimationFrame is close to the size of my answer. But that's sort of logical because the concept is straightforward. Made some edits above about that.

Comment: Thank you. With the link above and your comments, I made lots of progress.